# Understanding the attoparsec implementation (part 2)

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

I am currently trying to study and understand the source code of the `attoparsec` library, but there are some details I can't figure out myself. For example, the definition of the `Parser` type:

```
newtype Parser i a = Parser {
      runParser :: forall r.
                   State i -> Pos -> More
                -> Failure i (State i)   r
                -> Success i (State i) a r
                -> IResult i r
    }

newtype Pos = Pos { fromPos :: Int }
            deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Num)

data IResult i r =
    Fail i [String] String
  | Partial (i -> IResult i r)
  | Done i r

type Failure i t   r = t -> Pos -> More -> [String] -> String
                       -> IResult i r
type Success i t a r = t -> Pos -> More -> a -> IResult i r
```

What I don't fully understand yet is the usage of the type-parameter `r`. What would be different if I defined the type signature of `runParser` like this:

`State i -> Pos -> More -> Failure i (State i) a -> Success i (State i) a a -> IResult i a`

?

Can you please help me to understand what `forall r.` exactly means in this case and why it is necessary to use it in the `runParser`'s type signature?

Many thx in advance!

**UPDATE**: To clarify my question further: What I currently don't understand is why it is necessary to bring in the type-parameter `r` in the first place. One could imagine, that the `Parser` type could have been also defined like this:

```
newtype Parser i a = Parser {
      runParser ::
                   State i -> Pos -> More
                -> Failure i (State i) a
                -> Success i (State i) a
                -> IResult i a
}

data IResult i a =
    Fail i [String] String
    | Partial (i -> IResult i a)
    | Done i a

type Failure i t a  = t -> Pos -> More -> [String] -> String
                      -> IResult i a
type Success i t a = t -> Pos -> More -> a -> IResult i a
```

where the type-parameter `r` is not used at all. And my question is why this definition would be "wrong" and what problems it would entail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

attoparsec creates continuation passing style (CPS) parsers
and without the `forall` we wouldn't be able to chain
parsers together.

Here is a dramatically simplified version of the the
types involved and definition of `bindP` - the monadic bind operator.
We have eliminated the failure continuation and the input source.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

type IResult r = r
type Success a r = a -> IResult r  -- Success a r == a -> r

newtype Parser a = Parser {
      runParser :: forall r. Success a r
                -> IResult r
    }

bindP :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
bindP m g =
    Parser $ \ks -> runParser m $ \a -> runParser (g a) ks
                                                  -----
                                                  -----
```

Notes that `Success a r` is simply the function type `a -> r`.

If we replace the definition of `runParser` with:

```
runParser :: Success a a -> IResult a
```

we'll get a type error at the above underlined location.
To understand this one can work out the following types:

```
ks                                      :: Success b b
runParser m $ \a -> runParser (g a) ks  :: IResult b
\a -> runParser (g a) ks                :: Success b b  == b -> b
a :: b
```

but from the expression `(g a)` we can also conclude that `a` has type `a`
which gives us our type error.

Basically `Parser a` can be thought of as a method (or computation)
of generating value of type `a` and `runParser p ks` is the way to
take that value and feed it to a function which takes an `a`.
The continuation function `ks` can have type `a -> r` for any `r` - the
only requirement is that its input type is `a`.
By using `Success a a` in defining `runParser` we limit the
applicability of `runParser` to functions of type `a -> a`. That's why we
want to define `runParser` as:

```
runParser :: Parser a -> (a -> r) -> r
```

This CPS-style is a very different approach to parsing than what is presented
in [Monadic Parsing in Haskell](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/pearl.pdf)

Comment: Thats it! Thank you for the perfect explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The `forall r` part means that this type works for all `r` as your result without it needing to be specified on the left hand side of the `newtype` declaration.  As stated in the [Haskell wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types):

> The `forall` keyword is used to explicitly bring type variables into scope.

The `r` type variable isn't in scope until `forall` is used.  That wikibook page explains things pretty well with several examples, so I'll encourage you to look there, but the crux of the article is that `forall` acts like an intersection of types, so if you consider types as sets of elements, with `Bool = {False, True, ⊥}`, `Int = {minBound..maxBound, ⊥}`, `Char = {minBound..maxBound, ⊥}`, etc. (expand `minBound..maxBound` as appropriate, and `⊥` means undefined, usually called bottom), then

```
forall a. a
```

is the intersection of all types, namely `{⊥}`, while

```
forall a. Show a => a
```

is the intersection of all types that are constrained by `Show`.  In this context, when you have a type like

```
data T = forall a. MkT a
```

Then the constructor `MkT` has type `forall a. a -> T`, allowing you to convert any type into a `T`, this trick allows you to have heterogeneous lists:

```
[MkT (), MkT 1, MkT "hello"] :: [T]
```

But you can't do much with this type, how would you unwrap the `MkT` to do anything with it?  You could pattern match on the constructor, but then you'd just have a value of type `a` with no information about it.  If you had

```
data S = forall s. Show s => MkS s
```

Then you could do something like

```
-- Pass through instance of Show
instance Show S where show (MkS s) = show s

map show [MkS "hello", MkS 5, MkS (Just 2)]
["\"hello\"", "5", "Just 2"]
```

In the case of attoparsec, it is somewhat similar to the `ST` monad in how it uses the `forall` to prevent you from writing illegal operations.  Again, that wikibooks article provides a pretty good explanation.  If it isn't sufficient, comment and I'll see if I can clarify.

Comment: thx for the answer and the wikibook link. And I also have updated my question, so if you have time, could you look over it again and give me some examples why omitting the type parameter `r` would be problematic?

Comment: @bmk I'm not sure if I'm knowledgeable enough to elaborate on the design choices made in attoparsec.  You could try making that change and then re-implement a small subset of attoparsec with it to see what the difference is (what my course of action would be if I wanted to figure it out myself), or you could try emailing the maintainer, who would likely be able to explain it to you very easily and quickly.